# MySQL Substring between two DIFFERENT strings where the second needle comes AFTER the first

Tags: mysql

I have to extract certain data from a MySQL column.  The table looks like so:

```
+----+---------------------+------------------------+
| id |        time         |          data          |
+----+---------------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 2016-10-28 00:12:01 | a Q1!! AF3 !! ext!! z  |
|  2 | 2016-10-28 02:19:02 | z !!3F2 !AF66-2!! !!a  |
|  3 | 2016-10-28 11:35:03 | AF!a !!! pl6 f !!! dd  |
+----+---------------------+------------------------+
```

I want to grab the string from column `data` between the characters `AF` and the NEXT occurrence of `!!`  So ideally the query `SELECT`id`,[something] AS x FROM tbl` would result in:

```
+----+------+
| id |    x |
+----+------+
|  1 |   3  |
|  2 | 66-2 |
|  3 |  !a  |
+----+------+
```

Thoughts on how to do this?  All the other questions I see don't quite relate, as they don't deal with finding the first occurrence of the second needle (`!!`) AFTER the first needle (`AF`).

Comment: You can do this with a combination of `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions. Read about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be faster ways to do this but this is a good start:

```
 select substring_index(substring_index(data, 'AF', -1), '!!', 1)
```

Comment: There's no reference to the first needle, `AF`, in here.  Finding the first occurrence of the second needle (`==`) AFTER the first needle (`AF`) is the question.

Comment: Thanks @Bing. I shouldn't try to answer questions quickly before meetings. :)